# Xcode 4.1 GM Not Installing (must quit iTunes) on Lion?

Tags: xcode, itunes, osx-lion

I am trying to install Xcode 4.1 GM on my Lion mac but it's not working.  When it is almost finished, I get the popup to quit iTunes even though it is already quit.  So the only option I have is to quit iTunes helper or alert in activity monitor, then it finishes the install.  However then Xcode crashes on launch.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure its the XCode 4.1 GM on Lion GM?

Comment: A crash log would be helpful if it turns out you're use GM Xcode and Lion.  May be some hints in there.

Comment: Also try restarting your machine before installing- to make sure any iTunes/Xcode relevant processes have closed fully.

Comment: Yes lion gm and Xcode gm.  It keeps giving me the iTunes error. I even uninstalled Xcode and reinstalled.

Comment: I think it finally worked actually.

Comment: Xcode 4.1 RELEASE is free on the [Mac App Store](http://bit.ly/pDXpGC)

Comment: I had a similar issue after installing Xcode 4.1 on Lion - it kept crashing with an 'Internal Error'.
I rebooted Lion and then reinstalled Xcode from the binary downloaded from the Mac App Store and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can go into Activity Monitor and Quit the iTunes helper.  That will also get Xcode to finish.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Also wanted to say that it's not only a problem in GM. Makes sense, since GM is final anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've solved the install problem. It's not a solution per se, but setting Xcode to run in 32-bit mode fixed the crashing problem for me.

It's too early to say what the trade-off is (if any), but whatever it is, it's bound to be better than not being able to use it at all.

On a side note: please accept Phil's answer since he gave the correct solution to your original problem. C:

Answer (score 1):

if you boot into single user mode (Press S when starting up), the installation works as it should. Xcode will then function without switching it to 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Open "Activity Monitor" (press Command+Space to bring up spotlight, or find it in Applications.)

Sort by Process Name and find the process called "iTunesHelper".

From the "View" menu choose "Quit Process".

Then click on the "Force Quit" button. Xcode installation should continue now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the xCode through the Finder after you get this problem. It happened to me, but I can still run the xCode.

I think it's something to do with your version of itunes is more updated than your Mac Os version.