# Unable to install Xcode on Mac OS X Lion (10.7)

Tags: macos, xcode4, crash, installation, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.1 GM Not Installing (must quit iTunes) on Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740197/xcode-4-1-gm-not-installing-must-quit-itunes-on-lion)

I'm currently posting this as a question but it's also the answer.  I was so excited when I figured this out I just had to let everyone know who was stuck in the same boat as me.

I recently purchased a new MacBook Air and when I went to install Xcode, the installation would fail about half way and it would advise me to look at /var/log/install.log or something of that nature.  This seemed to be an Xcode 4 issue on Lion only.

If you've had this problem, simply follow these steps:

1) Install as NOT the root but still an administrative account
2) quit ALL instances of iTunes.  The one that lingers is iTunes Helper and it's the one that causes the installation to fail.  Use the Activity Monitor in Utilities to kill this process.
3) Install Xcode :)

And that's all folks!  I hope this helps anyone who was stuck in the same boat as me.

Cheers!
-Grahamzibar

Comment: SO is for programming questions!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Answering your own questions is very much encouraged around here, but it would be better to post your answer as an answer, instead of part of the question.  You could have earned a badge or two!  (And still can, by editing your question and posting an answer separately...)

Comment: @Randolf: I believe questions about usage of programming tools like Xcode are considered on-topic here, even if they're not specifically programming questions.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new to the site so I apologize for the redundancy.  I figured it was SOMEWHAT related to programming as it's used for it :P

Comment: p.s. thanks Ned for the other link!  That one is a great thread.  Would have saved me some typing time :P