# how to install XCode 4?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, xcode4, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.1 GM Not Installing (must quit iTunes) on Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740197/xcode-4-1-gm-not-installing-must-quit-itunes-on-lion)

I've downloaded XCode 4 from the App(le) store and started installation. After approx. 3/4 of the installation process, an installation alert tells to close iTunes. But iTunes is not running and I never run in before after installing a fresh (!) OS X 10.7. When clicking the zoom icon in this alert, it opens iTunes. Closing it does not change anything - the installation does not continue. Rebooting also does not help. What else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was (is?) a known problem. Open a terminal and try this:

```
killall iTunesHelper
```

Answer (score 1):

open a terminal.

become root with

```
su
```

locate the process

```
ps ax | grep tunes
```

kill the process with its id

```
kill -9 <id>
```

Comment: rather than becoming root with su, just use sudo with the kill command. Much less risky. `sudo kill -9 <id>`

Comment: indeed. it just happens to be that i love being root ;-)

Comment: so far i haven't `rm -f /`-ed my device (Do not try this @home kids!)

Comment: Just kill by name: `sudo killall iTunes`

Answer (score 1):

How are you closing iTunes? Are you just clicking the red X in the corner? This does not actually close the application on OS X, you have to go to the menu bar, click on iTunes, then click on Quit (or just hit Command-Q with iTunes in focus). Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok cool, I wondered because it took me awhile to get used to that when I started working on a Mac earlier this year.